# Can't apply CSS from Chrome Extension in user stylesheets

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, css

I'm trying to hide the ads from the right side of the emails in Gmail. For that I've made an extension that applies a CSS style.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/mail/*", "https://*/*"],
      "css": ["css/hide.css"]
    }
  ]
```

The content of `hide.css` is:

```
div.nH.HbF0O{ display: none; }
```

If I test this CSS in the file `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css`, the ads disappear. If I load the extension, it's not working.

If I introduce other styles in the CSS file, for example `body {display: none;}` or something simple, the CSS it's applied.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've just been playing around with a simple Chrome extension that applies some CSS styling and have found the web page's styling will take precedence over extension styling.

Try whacking an `!important` at the end of your declaration, e.g.

```
div.nH.HbF0O { display: none !important; }
```

and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long shot, but I guess I've never seen CSS code like `div.nH.HbF0O{ display: none; }`.

- Did you mean `div.nH, div.HbF0O{ display: none; }` ?
- or you mean "descendant" and miss a whitespace: `div.nH .HbF0O{ display: none; }` ?

Edit:
I've checked that CSS `div.nH.HbF0O{}` can refer to HTML `<div class="nH HbF0O" />` so I might be wrong.

Comment: But then why does it work from `User StyleSheets`?